# Recuperar sessão pelo sessionStorage

Tags: php

Boa noite, minha dúvida é bem simples gostaria de saber como faço pra exibir o nome do usuário da sessão no console. Tentei dessa forma mais só retorna null.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['usuario'] = 'Pedro';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>teste</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var teste = sessionStorage.getItem('usuario');
    console.log(teste);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sessão do PHP é uma coisa, sessionStorage do JS é outra completamente diferente. Uma fica no servidor, outra no cliente. Em qual das duas você armazenou o nome do usuário?

Comment: eu armazenei no servidor, mas eu queria pegar o dado da sessão pelo sessionStorage

Comment: Impossível. Pesquise sobre os conceitos de client-side e server-side.

Comment: Então como que eu faria pra recuperar o nome do usuário ? Ou também não tem como ?

Comment: Através de `$_SESSION['usuario']`, como fez no início.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa setar o dado que atualmente está na sessão do **php** no `sessionstorage`

```
sessionStorage.setItem('usuario', '<?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']?>');
```

Após isso você pode pegar o dado do usuári com

```
var teste = sessionStorage.getItem('usuario');
console.log(teste);
```

Comment: deu certinho, vlw